# Python Pandas how to update a column if another column contains a certain string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a dataframe and I want to replace the value in MinP with the value in MaxP ONLY if MaxP has a +/-
[I will then remove the +/- and convert to a number]

My code kind of works but it puts a 0 in MinP when Maxp does not have a +/- instead I want to keep the value, if any, of MinP

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'MinP':['0','','-10','',],
    'MaxP':['20','15','12','+/-20']})

print(df)

df['MinP'] = df['MaxP'].apply(lambda x: df['MaxP'] if '+/-' in x else df['MinP'])
print(df)

    MinP   MaxP
0    0     20
1          15
2  -10     12
3       +/-20
    MinP   MaxP
0    0     20
1    0     15
2    0     12
3   20  +/-20
```

I also played around with:
df.loc[df['MinP']] = np.where(df.MaxP.str.contains("+/-"), df['MaxP'],df.MinP)
but didn't get anywhere.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) + [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['MinP'] = np.where(df.MaxP.str.contains('+/-', regex=False), df.MaxP, df.MinP)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    MinP   MaxP
0      0     20
1            15
2    -10     12
3  +/-20  +/-20
```

Notice that you must use `regex=False` to avoid the pattern being interpreted as a regular expression.

Answer (score 3):

`+` is a special char in regex, so you need to do `contains('\+/-')`. Also, `fillna` is handy:

```
df['MinP'] = df.MaxP.str.extract('^\+/-(\d+)')[0].fillna(df.MinP)
```

Output:

```
 MinP   MaxP
0    0     20
1          15
2  -10     12
3   20  +/-20
```

---

**Note**: `'^\+/-(\d+)'` only extract the digits. If your data contains other characters, e.g. `20.1` or `2e10`, you can use `'^\+/-(.+)'`